# howto: setup a bidirectional UDP connection for a message based communication

Tags: c, sockets, udp, communication

The problem I want to solve is to build a stable connection for exchanging data between a PC and my Raspberry Pi(RPi). They are connected via WLAN in a LAN by a router.

I created a simple way, by defining on every device a client(c) and a server(s). I give in short the pseudo-code for that:

```
@init:
s = createSocket
c = createSocket
s = bind to "localhost"
create thread for message handling

@message handling thread:
msg = recvfrom(s)

@main:
init(serverPort=10001, clientIP="raspberryPi", clientPort=10002)
sendto(c, "hello")
```

The problem with UDP via WLAN is, that some messages can get lost.  So I decided to create a simple protocol for that data exchange. The idea is that the server acknowledges the reception of the data. The problem changes into that kind pseudo-code:

```
@init:
s = createSocket
c = createSocket
s = bind to "localhost"
create thread for message handling

@message handling thread:
msg = recvfrom(s)
sendto (c, "ack")

@main:
sendto(c, "hello")
wait for 100ms for res = recvfrom(s)
if res == timeout goto sendto
if res <> 'ack' wrong message
```

I am running into a problem, that the sending and receiving process using both recvfrom(s). Also the easy loop back test by using the same port for client and server can not be done.

Any ideas?

Some not working c code follows:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#include <pthread.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <errno.h>

// sockets
#ifdef WIN32
    #ifndef WINVER
        // set min win version to Win XP
        #define WINVER 0x0501
    #endif
    //use lib: ws2_32
    #include <winsock2.h>
    #include <ws2tcpip.h>
#else

    #include <sys/types.h>
    #include <sys/socket.h>
    #include <netinet/in.h>
    #include <netdb.h>

    #include <sys/un.h>
    #include <unistd.h>
    #include <arpa/inet.h>

    #define ADDR_ANY    INADDR_ANY
    #define SOCKET_ERROR    (-1)
    #define INVALID_SOCKET (SOCKET)(~0)
    #define closesocket(x) (close(x))

    typedef int SOCKET;
    typedef struct sockaddr_in SOCKADDR_IN;
    typedef struct sockaddr SOCKADDR;

#endif


typedef int (* TfkpTCPcallback) (uint8_t * pData, size_t amount);

// size of the header
#define dStjTCPSocketControlMsg (sizeof(uint_32))

// start data msg struct
// <uint_32> id = 's'
// <uint_32> len

// res struct
// <uint_32> id = 'r'
// <uint_32> error code (0 = no error)

enum eStjTCPSocketControlMsgIDs {
    eStjTCPSocketControlMsgID_start = 's',
    eStjTCPSocketControlMsgID_result = 'r'
};

enum eStjTCPSocketControlMsgErrorIDs {
    eStjTCPSocketControlMsgErrorID_noError = 0,
    eStjTCPSocketControlMsgErrorID_otherError,
    eStjTCPSocketControlMsgErrorID_socket,
    eStjTCPSocketControlMsgErrorID_msgID,
    eStjTCPSocketControlMsgErrorID_realloc,
    eStjTCPSocketControlMsgErrorID_amount,

};

//! type to control a udp socket based message communication
typedef struct SstjTCPSocketControl {
    pthread_t           srvThr;

    SOCKET              sCli;   //!< socket for the input
    SOCKET              sSrv;   //!< socket for the output

    struct sockaddr_in  sAddrCli; //!< client address
    int                 cliConnectedFlag; //!< <>0 if the client is connected

    uint8_t *           pMsgBuffer;
    size_t              msgBufferSize;

    sem_t               serverSign;
    TfkpTCPcallback     rxCB;
} TstjTCPSocketControl;

//! a global variable to control a udp message based communication
TstjTCPSocketControl gTCPsocketControl = {
    .srvThr = NULL,
    .sCli = -1,
    .sSrv = -1,
    .cliConnectedFlag = 0,
    .pMsgBuffer = NULL,
    .msgBufferSize = 0,
};

int recvResult(SOCKET s) {
    int r;
    uint32_t contrlMsg[2];

    // recv that the server is ready to transmit
    r = recv(s , (char *)contrlMsg , sizeof(contrlMsg) , 0);
    if(r < 0) {
        return eStjTCPSocketControlMsgErrorID_socket;
    }
    if (r != sizeof(contrlMsg)) {
        return eStjTCPSocketControlMsgErrorID_amount;
    }
    if (contrlMsg[0] != eStjTCPSocketControlMsgID_result) {
        return eStjTCPSocketControlMsgErrorID_msgID;
    }

    return contrlMsg[1];
}

int sendResult(SOCKET s, uint32_t errorCode) {
    uint32_t contrlMsg[2];
    int r;

    contrlMsg[0] = eStjTCPSocketControlMsgID_result;
    contrlMsg[1] = errorCode;
    r = send(s , (char *)contrlMsg , sizeof(contrlMsg) , 0);
    if (r < 0) return eStjTCPSocketControlMsgErrorID_socket;
    return eStjTCPSocketControlMsgErrorID_noError;
}

//! sends a block of data
int TCPcontrolSend(uint8_t * pD, size_t dataSize) {
    int r;
    uint32_t contrlMsg[2];

    // check if we have to connect
    if (!gTCPsocketControl.cliConnectedFlag) {
        if (connect(gTCPsocketControl.sCli , (struct sockaddr *)&gTCPsocketControl.sAddrCli , sizeof(gTCPsocketControl.sAddrCli)) < 0){
            gTCPsocketControl.cliConnectedFlag = 0;
            return -1;
        } else {
            gTCPsocketControl.cliConnectedFlag = 1;
        }

    }
    //  ok we are connected - lets send the data
    start:

    contrlMsg[0] = eStjTCPSocketControlMsgID_start;
    contrlMsg[1] = dataSize;
    // send that we what to transmit some data
    r = send(gTCPsocketControl.sCli , (char *)contrlMsg , sizeof(contrlMsg) , 0);
    if(r < 0) {
        return -2;
    }
    // recv that the server is ready to transmit
    r = recvResult(gTCPsocketControl.sCli);
    if (eStjTCPSocketControlMsgErrorID_socket == r) return -3;
    if (eStjTCPSocketControlMsgErrorID_amount == r) goto start;

    // ok let's send
    r = send(gTCPsocketControl.sCli , pD ,dataSize , 0);
    if(r < 0) {
        return -2;
    }
    // get ack from the server
    r = recvResult(gTCPsocketControl.sCli);
    if (eStjTCPSocketControlMsgErrorID_socket == r) return -3;
    if (eStjTCPSocketControlMsgErrorID_amount == r) goto start;
    return r;
}


//! the message pump
void * TCPcontrolMsgPump (void *pParams) {
    int                 r;
    uint32_t            contrlMsg[2];
    struct sockaddr_in  cliAddr;
    SOCKET              sCli;
    uint32_t            dataSize;
    socklen_t           cliAddrSize;

    sem_post(&gTCPsocketControl.serverSign);

    //accept connection from an incoming client
    cliAddrSize = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
    sCli = accept(gTCPsocketControl.sSrv, (struct sockaddr *)&cliAddr, (socklen_t*)&cliAddrSize);
    if (sCli < 0) goto end;

    // run the pump
    for (;;) {
        // ok we are connected
        // read start message
        r = recv(sCli , (char *)contrlMsg , sizeof(contrlMsg), 0);
        if (r < 0) goto end;
        if (r != sizeof(contrlMsg)) {
            sendResult(sCli, eStjTCPSocketControlMsgErrorID_amount);
            continue;
        }
        if (contrlMsg[0] != eStjTCPSocketControlMsgID_start) {
            sendResult(sCli, eStjTCPSocketControlMsgErrorID_msgID);
            continue;
        }

        dataSize = contrlMsg[1];
        // check if we have to realloc the rx buffer
        if (gTCPsocketControl.msgBufferSize < dataSize) {
             uint8_t *pNB = realloc(gTCPsocketControl.pMsgBuffer, dataSize);
             if (!pNB) {
                 sendResult(sCli, eStjTCPSocketControlMsgErrorID_realloc);
                 continue;
             }
             gTCPsocketControl.pMsgBuffer = pNB;
             gTCPsocketControl.msgBufferSize = dataSize;
        }

        sendResult(sCli, eStjTCPSocketControlMsgErrorID_noError);

        // recv data
        r = recv(sCli , gTCPsocketControl.pMsgBuffer , gTCPsocketControl.msgBufferSize, 0);
        if (r < 0) goto end;
        if (r != dataSize) {
            sendResult(sCli, eStjTCPSocketControlMsgErrorID_amount);
            continue;
        }
        sendResult(sCli, eStjTCPSocketControlMsgErrorID_noError);

        // handle message
        gTCPsocketControl.rxCB(gTCPsocketControl.pMsgBuffer , gTCPsocketControl.msgBufferSize);
        continue;
    }
end:
    sem_post(&gTCPsocketControl.serverSign);
    return (void *) -1;
}

//! init
int TCPcontrolInit (
        int             serverPort, //!< server tx port number - best over 1000
        const char *    szClient,       //!< "family-PC" or "192.168.1.3"
        int             clientPort, //!< client tx port number
        TfkpTCPcallback rxCB,           //!< the rx data callback
        long            timeOut,        //!< the time out of the rx operation in ms
        size_t          rxBufferSize,   //!< the size of the rx buffer
        size_t          maxTCPdataSize  //!< maximum size of a TCP datagram (400 Bytes seems a good size)
    ) {
#ifdef WIN32
    // local data
    WSADATA     wsaData;

    // start sockets
    if ((WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData))) {
        perror("WSAStartup failed!");
        return -1;
    }
#endif
    char *              szIPserver;
    char *              szIPclient;
    struct hostent *    pHostDescr;
    struct sockaddr_in  sAddr;

    //if (serverPort == clientPort) return -1;

    // -----------------
    // get ip strings

    // get ip of the server
    pHostDescr = gethostbyname("localhost");
    // check if found a host
    if (!pHostDescr) {
        return -11;
    }
    szIPserver = inet_ntoa(*(struct in_addr*)*pHostDescr->h_addr_list);

    // get ip of the client
    if (strcmp(szClient, "")) {
        pHostDescr = gethostbyname(szClient);
    } else {
        pHostDescr = gethostbyname("localhost");
    }
    // check if found a host
    if (!pHostDescr) {
        return -12;
    }
    szIPclient = inet_ntoa(*(struct in_addr*)*pHostDescr->h_addr_list);


    // -----------------
    // try to create sockets

    // try to create socket for the server
    gTCPsocketControl.sSrv = socket(PF_INET , SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    if (-1 == gTCPsocketControl.sSrv) return -21;
    // try to create socket for the client
    gTCPsocketControl.sCli = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    if (-1 == gTCPsocketControl.sCli) return -22;

    // -----------------
    // bind input to IP and port
    memset(&sAddr,0,sizeof(sAddr));
    sAddr.sin_family = PF_INET;
    sAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    sAddr.sin_port = htons( serverPort );

    // bind server socket to address
    if (bind(gTCPsocketControl.sSrv, (SOCKADDR *)&sAddr, sizeof(SOCKADDR_IN))) {
        return -31;
    }
    // and listen for incoming connections
    if (listen(gTCPsocketControl.sSrv , 3)) {
        return -32;
    }

    // -----------------
    // connect output to IP and port
    memset(&gTCPsocketControl.sAddrCli,0,sizeof(sAddr));
    gTCPsocketControl.sAddrCli.sin_family = PF_INET;
    gTCPsocketControl.sAddrCli.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(szIPclient);
    gTCPsocketControl.sAddrCli.sin_port = htons( clientPort );

    if (connect(gTCPsocketControl.sCli , (struct sockaddr *)&gTCPsocketControl.sAddrCli , sizeof(gTCPsocketControl.sAddrCli)) < 0){
        gTCPsocketControl.cliConnectedFlag = 0;
    } else {
        gTCPsocketControl.cliConnectedFlag = 1;
    }


    // create sign semaphore
    sem_init(&gTCPsocketControl.serverSign, 0, 0);

    // create buffers
    gTCPsocketControl.pMsgBuffer = malloc(rxBufferSize);
    if (!gTCPsocketControl.pMsgBuffer) {
        return -32;
    }
    gTCPsocketControl.msgBufferSize = rxBufferSize;

    // set callback
    gTCPsocketControl.rxCB = rxCB;

    // start rx thread
    if(pthread_create(&gTCPsocketControl.srvThr , NULL, TCPcontrolMsgPump, NULL)) {
        return -40;
    }
    // wait till rx server is running
    sem_wait(&gTCPsocketControl.serverSign);

    return 0;
}

//! closes the TCP server and client
void TCPcontrolClose () {
    closesocket (gTCPsocketControl.sSrv);
    closesocket (gTCPsocketControl.sCli);

    free(gTCPsocketControl.pMsgBuffer);

    memset(&gTCPsocketControl, 0, sizeof(TstjTCPSocketControl));

#ifdef WIN32
    WSACleanup();
#endif
}

// -----------------------------------------
// test

int stFlag = 0;
#define  dSTsize (1024 * 1024)
uint8_t STB[dSTsize];


int rxCB (uint8_t * pData, size_t amount) {
    if (!stFlag) {
        pData[amount] = 0;
        printf("rx: %s\n",pData);
    } else {
        size_t i;
        for (i = 0; i < dSTsize; i++) {
            if (pData[i] != (uint8_t)((size_t)i & 0xFF)) {
                fprintf(stderr, "stress test error at position %i\n",(int) i);
                return 0;
            }
        }
        printf("rx: stress test successful\n");
    }
    fflush(stdout);
    return 0;
}


int main(void) {
    int srvPort;
    int clientPort;
    const size_t ipLen = 256;
    char szIP[ipLen];
    const size_t dummyStrLen = 1024;
    char szDummy[dummyStrLen];
    size_t i;
    int r;

    // pre init for the stress test
    for (i = 0; i < dSTsize; i++) {
        STB[i] = (uint8_t)((size_t)i & 0xFF);
    }


    printf("TCP demo\n");

    printf("enter server port: ");
    fgets(szDummy, dummyStrLen, stdin);
    szDummy[strcspn(szDummy, "\r\n")] = 0;
    srvPort = atoi(szDummy);

    printf("enter IP address of the other server: ");
    fgets(szIP, 255, stdin);
    szIP[strcspn(szIP, "\r\n")] = 0;

    printf("enter client port: ");
    fgets(szDummy, dummyStrLen, stdin);
    szDummy[strcspn(szDummy, "\r\n")] = 0;
    clientPort = atoi(szDummy);

    if (TCPcontrolInit (
            srvPort,    //!< server port number - best over 1000
            szIP,   //!< "family-PC" or "192.168.1.3"
            clientPort, //!< client port number
            rxCB,       //!< the rx data callback
            100,    //!< the time out of the rx operation in ms
            10,//!< the size of the rx buffer
            400 //!< maximum size of a TCP datagram (400 Bytes seems a good size)
        ) < 0 ){
        fprintf(stderr, "TCP control setup failed!");
        goto errorExit;
    }

    printf("commands:\n s - send\n t - tx stress test\n a - activate/deactivate rx for stress test\n h - help\n e - exit\n");
    for(;;) {
        printf("command: ");
        fgets(szDummy, dummyStrLen, stdin);
        switch(tolower(szDummy[0])) {
            case 's':
                fgets(szDummy, dummyStrLen, stdin);
                szDummy[strcspn(szDummy, "\r\n")] = 0;
                r = TCPcontrolSend((uint8_t *)szDummy, strlen(szDummy)+1);
                if(r) {
                    fprintf(stderr,"sending data failed with code %i(%s)\n", r, strerror(errno));
                }
                break;
            case 't':
                r = TCPcontrolSend(STB, dSTsize);
                if (r) {
                    fprintf(stderr,"stress test sending data failed with code %i\n", r);
                }
                break;
            case 'a':
                stFlag = (!stFlag) ? 1 : 0;
                if (stFlag) {
                    printf("stress test RX now active\n");
                } else {
                    printf("stress test RX deactivated\n");
                }
                break;
            case 'h':
                printf("commands:\n s - send\n t - tx stress test\n a - activate/deactivate rx for stress test\n h - help\n e - exit\n");
                break;
            case 'e':
                goto stdExit;
        }
    }

stdExit:

    TCPcontrolClose ();
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;

errorExit:

    TCPcontrolClose ();
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```

Comment: To achieve *reliable packet-oriented bi-directional communication*, you can either A) add reliability to UDP, or B) add a packet layer to TCP. I've always chosen B, since it's much much easier.

Comment: @TCP: is there a tutorial describing that available?

Comment: You realize that `recvfrom()` gives you the source address? You don't need both peers running a server.

Comment: Tutorial -- On the transmit side, compose a packet with a two byte start code (0xAA 0x55), a two byte length (MSB first), the payload, and a two byte end code (0x33 0xCC). Send packet over TCP with `send`.  On the receive side, call `recv` as many times as necessary to get the first 4 bytes (verify the start code). Call `recv` as many times as necessary to get the rest of the packet (the payload and end code). Verify the end code. The purpose of the start/end codes is to help you during development/debugging. If your code is perfect, the start/end codes will never be wrong, TCP won't allow it.

Comment: I modified my code to TCP. It works fine in the loopback. To test the code I have several scenarios:
1st - Win to Win on PC
2nd - Win to Ubuntu(a virtualBox) on PC
3d - Ubuntu(a virtualBox) on PC to RPi
4th - Win on PC to RPi
It seems that there is a problem connecting to a server located outside of the OS.
I changed the code listing above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The TCP approach works fine. With the code below a full duplex connection with asynchronous RX TX works fine. Its tested in Linux and Windows:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#include <pthread.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <errno.h>

// sockets
#ifdef WIN32
    #ifndef WINVER
        // set min win version to Win XP
        #define WINVER 0x0501
    #endif
    //use lib: ws2_32
    #include <winsock2.h>
    #include <ws2tcpip.h>
#else

    #include <sys/types.h>
    #include <sys/socket.h>
    #include <netinet/in.h>
    #include <netdb.h>

    #include <sys/un.h>
    #include <unistd.h>
    #include <arpa/inet.h>

    #define ADDR_ANY    INADDR_ANY
    #define SOCKET_ERROR    (-1)
    #define INVALID_SOCKET (SOCKET)(~0)
    #define closesocket(x) (close(x))

    typedef int SOCKET;
    typedef struct sockaddr_in SOCKADDR_IN;
    typedef struct sockaddr SOCKADDR;

#endif


typedef int (* TfkpTCPcallback) (uint8_t * pData, size_t amount);

// size of the header
#define dStjTCPSocketControlMsg (sizeof(uint_32))

// start data msg struct
// <uint_32> id = 's'
// <uint_32> len

// res struct
// <uint_32> id = 'r'
// <uint_32> error code (0 = no error)

enum eStjTCPSocketControlMsgIDs {
    eStjTCPSocketControlMsgID_start = 's',
    eStjTCPSocketControlMsgID_packet = 'p',
    eStjTCPSocketControlMsgID_result = 'r'
};

enum eStjTCPSocketControlMsgErrorIDs {
    eStjTCPSocketControlMsgErrorID_noError = 0,
    eStjTCPSocketControlMsgErrorID_otherError,
    eStjTCPSocketControlMsgErrorID_socket,
    eStjTCPSocketControlMsgErrorID_msgID,
    eStjTCPSocketControlMsgErrorID_realloc,
    eStjTCPSocketControlMsgErrorID_amount,
    eStjTCPSocketControlMsgErrorID_wrongPacket,

};

//! type to control a udp socket based message communication
typedef struct SstjTCPSocketControl {
    pthread_t           srvThr;

    SOCKET              sCli;   //!< socket for the input
    SOCKET              sSrv;   //!< socket for the output

    struct sockaddr_in  sAddrCli; //!< client address
    int                 cliConnectedFlag; //!< <>0 if the client is connected

    uint8_t *           pMsgBuffer;
    size_t              msgBufferSize;

    sem_t               serverSign;
    TfkpTCPcallback     rxCB;

    int                 maxTXsize;
} TstjTCPSocketControl;

//! a global variable to control a udp message based communication
TstjTCPSocketControl gTCPsocketControl = {
    .srvThr = NULL,
    .sCli = -1,
    .sSrv = -1,
    .cliConnectedFlag = 0,
    .pMsgBuffer = NULL,
    .msgBufferSize = 0,
};

static inline int _TCPcontrolRecvResult(SOCKET s) {
    int r;
    uint32_t contrlMsg[2];

    // recv that the server is ready to transmit
    r = recv(s , (char *)contrlMsg , sizeof(contrlMsg) , 0);
    if(r < 0) {
        return eStjTCPSocketControlMsgErrorID_socket;
    }
    if (r != sizeof(contrlMsg)) {
        return eStjTCPSocketControlMsgErrorID_amount;
    }
    if (contrlMsg[0] != eStjTCPSocketControlMsgID_result) {
        return eStjTCPSocketControlMsgErrorID_msgID;
    }

    return contrlMsg[1];
}

static inline int _TCPcontrolSendResult(SOCKET s, uint32_t errorCode) {
    uint32_t contrlMsg[2];
    int r;

    contrlMsg[0] = eStjTCPSocketControlMsgID_result;
    contrlMsg[1] = errorCode;
    r = send(s , (char *)contrlMsg , sizeof(contrlMsg) , 0);
    if (r < 0) return eStjTCPSocketControlMsgErrorID_socket;
    return eStjTCPSocketControlMsgErrorID_noError;
}

//! sends a block of data
int TCPcontrolSend(uint8_t * pD, size_t dataSize) {
    int r;
    uint32_t contrlMsg[2];
    uint32_t p;
    uint32_t packets;
    uint8_t * pB;
    size_t  am, amTotal;

    // check if we have to connect
    if (!gTCPsocketControl.cliConnectedFlag) {
        if (connect(gTCPsocketControl.sCli , (struct sockaddr *)&gTCPsocketControl.sAddrCli , sizeof(gTCPsocketControl.sAddrCli)) < 0){
            gTCPsocketControl.cliConnectedFlag = 0;
            return -1;
        } else {
            gTCPsocketControl.cliConnectedFlag = 1;
        }

    }
    //  ok we are connected - lets send the data
    start:

    contrlMsg[0] = eStjTCPSocketControlMsgID_start;
    contrlMsg[1] = dataSize;
    // send that we what to transmit some data
    r = send(gTCPsocketControl.sCli , (char *)contrlMsg , sizeof(contrlMsg) , 0);
    if(r < 0) {
        return -2;
    }
    // recv that the server is ready to transmit
    r = _TCPcontrolRecvResult(gTCPsocketControl.sCli);
    if (eStjTCPSocketControlMsgErrorID_socket == r) return -3;
    if (eStjTCPSocketControlMsgErrorID_amount == r) goto start;

    // ok let's send
    packets = dataSize / gTCPsocketControl.maxTXsize;
    if (dataSize % gTCPsocketControl.maxTXsize) packets++;
    pB = pD;
    amTotal = dataSize;

    for (p = 0; p < packets; p++) {
        // send packet pre header
        contrlMsg[0] = eStjTCPSocketControlMsgID_packet;
        contrlMsg[1] = p;
        r = send(gTCPsocketControl.sCli , (char *)contrlMsg , sizeof(contrlMsg) , 0);
        if(r < 0) {
            return -4;
        }
        r = _TCPcontrolRecvResult(gTCPsocketControl.sCli);
        if (eStjTCPSocketControlMsgErrorID_socket == r) return -5;
        if (eStjTCPSocketControlMsgErrorID_amount == r) goto start;

        am = (amTotal > gTCPsocketControl.maxTXsize) ? gTCPsocketControl.maxTXsize : amTotal;

sendPacket:
        r = send(gTCPsocketControl.sCli ,(char *) pB ,am , 0);
        if(r < 0) {
            return -5;
        }

        // get ack from the server
        r = _TCPcontrolRecvResult(gTCPsocketControl.sCli);
        if (eStjTCPSocketControlMsgErrorID_socket == r) return -3;
        if (eStjTCPSocketControlMsgErrorID_amount == r) goto sendPacket;

        pB += am;
        amTotal -= am;
    }
    return r;
}


//! the message pump
void * TCPcontrolMsgPump (void *pParams) {
    int                 r;
    uint32_t            contrlMsg[2];
    struct sockaddr_in  cliAddr;
    SOCKET              sCli;
    uint32_t            dataSize;
    socklen_t           cliAddrSize;
    uint32_t            packets;
    uint8_t *           pB;
    size_t              am, amTotal;
    uint32_t            p;


    sem_post(&gTCPsocketControl.serverSign);

    //accept connection from an incoming client
    cliAddrSize = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
    sCli = accept(gTCPsocketControl.sSrv, (struct sockaddr *)&cliAddr, (socklen_t*)&cliAddrSize);
    if (sCli < 0) goto end;

    // run the pump
    for (;;) {
        // ok we are connected
        // read start message
        r = recv(sCli , (char *)contrlMsg , sizeof(contrlMsg), 0);
        if (r < 0) goto end;
        if (r != sizeof(contrlMsg)) {
            _TCPcontrolSendResult(sCli, eStjTCPSocketControlMsgErrorID_amount);
            continue;
        }
        if (contrlMsg[0] != eStjTCPSocketControlMsgID_start) {
            _TCPcontrolSendResult(sCli, eStjTCPSocketControlMsgErrorID_msgID);
            continue;
        }

        dataSize = contrlMsg[1];
        // check if we have to realloc the rx buffer
        if (gTCPsocketControl.msgBufferSize < dataSize) {
             uint8_t *pNB = realloc(gTCPsocketControl.pMsgBuffer, dataSize);
             if (!pNB) {
                 _TCPcontrolSendResult(sCli, eStjTCPSocketControlMsgErrorID_realloc);
                 continue;
             }
             gTCPsocketControl.pMsgBuffer = pNB;
             gTCPsocketControl.msgBufferSize = dataSize;
        }

        _TCPcontrolSendResult(sCli, eStjTCPSocketControlMsgErrorID_noError);

        // recv data
        packets = dataSize / gTCPsocketControl.maxTXsize;
        if (dataSize % gTCPsocketControl.maxTXsize) packets++;
        pB = gTCPsocketControl.pMsgBuffer;
        amTotal = dataSize;

        for (p = 0; p < packets; p++) {
            // receive packet header
            r = recv(sCli , (char *)contrlMsg , sizeof(contrlMsg), 0);
            if (r < 0) goto end;
            if (r != sizeof(contrlMsg)) {
                _TCPcontrolSendResult(sCli, eStjTCPSocketControlMsgErrorID_amount);
                continue;
            }
            if (contrlMsg[0] != eStjTCPSocketControlMsgID_packet) {
                _TCPcontrolSendResult(sCli, eStjTCPSocketControlMsgErrorID_msgID);
                continue;
            }
            if (contrlMsg[1] != p) {
                _TCPcontrolSendResult(sCli, eStjTCPSocketControlMsgErrorID_wrongPacket);
                continue;
            }
            _TCPcontrolSendResult(sCli, eStjTCPSocketControlMsgErrorID_noError);

            am = (amTotal > gTCPsocketControl.maxTXsize) ? gTCPsocketControl.maxTXsize : amTotal;

            // ok the next message will contain the data
recvPacket:
            r = recv(sCli , (char *)pB , am, 0);
            if (r < 0) goto end;
            if (r != am) {
                _TCPcontrolSendResult(sCli, eStjTCPSocketControlMsgErrorID_amount);
                goto recvPacket;
            }

            _TCPcontrolSendResult(sCli, eStjTCPSocketControlMsgErrorID_noError);
            pB += am;
            amTotal -= am;
        }

        // handle message
        gTCPsocketControl.rxCB(gTCPsocketControl.pMsgBuffer , dataSize);
        continue;
    }
end:
    sem_post(&gTCPsocketControl.serverSign);
    return (void *) -1;
}

//! init
int TCPcontrolInit (
        int             serverPort,     //!< server tx port number - best over 1000
        const char *    szClient,       //!< "family-PC" or "192.168.1.3"
        int             clientPort,     //!< client tx port number
        TfkpTCPcallback rxCB,           //!< the rx data callback
        size_t          rxBufferSize,   //!< the size of the rx buffer
        size_t          maxTCPdataSize  //!< maximum size of a TCP datagram (400 Bytes seems a good size)
    ) {
#ifdef WIN32
    // local data
    WSADATA     wsaData;

    // start sockets
    if ((WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData))) {
        perror("WSAStartup failed!");
        return -1;
    }
#endif
    char *              szIPserver;
    char *              szIPclient;
    struct hostent *    pHostDescr;
    struct sockaddr_in  sAddr;

    // -----------------
    // get ip strings

    // get ip of the server
    pHostDescr = gethostbyname("localhost");
    // check if found a host
    if (!pHostDescr) {
        return -11;
    }
    szIPserver = inet_ntoa(*(struct in_addr*)*pHostDescr->h_addr_list);

    // get ip of the client
    if (strcmp(szClient, "")) {
        pHostDescr = gethostbyname(szClient);
    } else {
        pHostDescr = gethostbyname("localhost");
    }
    // check if found a host
    if (!pHostDescr) {
        return -12;
    }
    szIPclient = inet_ntoa(*(struct in_addr*)*pHostDescr->h_addr_list);


    // -----------------
    // try to create sockets

    // try to create socket for the server
    gTCPsocketControl.sSrv = socket(PF_INET , SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    if (-1 == gTCPsocketControl.sSrv) return -21;
    // try to create socket for the client
    gTCPsocketControl.sCli = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    if (-1 == gTCPsocketControl.sCli) return -22;

    // -----------------
    // bind input to IP and port
    memset(&sAddr,0,sizeof(sAddr));
    sAddr.sin_family = PF_INET;
    sAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    sAddr.sin_port = htons( serverPort );

    // bind server socket to address
    if (bind(gTCPsocketControl.sSrv, (SOCKADDR *)&sAddr, sizeof(SOCKADDR_IN))) {
        return -31;
    }
    // and listen for incoming connections
    if (listen(gTCPsocketControl.sSrv , 3)) {
        return -32;
    }

    // -----------------
    // connect output to IP and port
    memset(&gTCPsocketControl.sAddrCli,0,sizeof(sAddr));
    gTCPsocketControl.sAddrCli.sin_family = PF_INET;
    gTCPsocketControl.sAddrCli.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(szIPclient);
    gTCPsocketControl.sAddrCli.sin_port = htons( clientPort );

    if (connect(gTCPsocketControl.sCli , (struct sockaddr *)&gTCPsocketControl.sAddrCli , sizeof(gTCPsocketControl.sAddrCli)) < 0){
        gTCPsocketControl.cliConnectedFlag = 0;
    } else {
        gTCPsocketControl.cliConnectedFlag = 1;
    }


    // create sign semaphore
    sem_init(&gTCPsocketControl.serverSign, 0, 0);

    // create buffers
    gTCPsocketControl.pMsgBuffer = malloc(rxBufferSize);
    if (!gTCPsocketControl.pMsgBuffer) {
        return -32;
    }
    gTCPsocketControl.msgBufferSize = rxBufferSize;

    // set callback
    gTCPsocketControl.rxCB = rxCB;

    gTCPsocketControl.maxTXsize = maxTCPdataSize;

    // start rx thread
    if(pthread_create(&gTCPsocketControl.srvThr , NULL, TCPcontrolMsgPump, NULL)) {
        return -40;
    }
    // wait till rx server is running
    sem_wait(&gTCPsocketControl.serverSign);

    return 0;
}

//! closes the TCP server and client
void TCPcontrolClose () {
    closesocket (gTCPsocketControl.sSrv);
    closesocket (gTCPsocketControl.sCli);

    free(gTCPsocketControl.pMsgBuffer);

    memset(&gTCPsocketControl, 0, sizeof(TstjTCPSocketControl));

#ifdef WIN32
    WSACleanup();
#endif
}


//! inits the TCP control via stdin inputs
int TCPcontrolInitFromStdIn (
        TfkpTCPcallback rxCB,           //!< the rx data callback
        size_t          rxBufferSize,   //!< the size of the rx buffer
        size_t          maxTCPdataSize  //!< maximum size of a TCP datagram (400 Bytes seems a good size)
    ) {
    int srvPort;
    int clientPort;
    const size_t ipLen = 256;
    char szIP[ipLen];
    const size_t dummyStrLen = 100;
    char szDummy[dummyStrLen];

    int r;

    printf("====| TCP client/server setup |====\n");
    printf("server listen port: ");
    fgets(szDummy, dummyStrLen, stdin);
    szDummy[strcspn(szDummy, "\r\n")] = 0;
    srvPort = atoi(szDummy);

    printf("client send IP address or name: ");
    fgets(szIP, 255, stdin);
    szIP[strcspn(szIP, "\r\n")] = 0;

    printf("client port: ");
    fgets(szDummy, dummyStrLen, stdin);
    szDummy[strcspn(szDummy, "\r\n")] = 0;
    clientPort = atoi(szDummy);

    r = TCPcontrolInit (
            srvPort,        //!< server port number - best over 1000
            szIP,           //!< "family-PC" or "192.168.1.3"
            clientPort,     //!< client port number
            rxCB,           //!< the rx data callback
            rxBufferSize,   //!< the size of the rx buffer
            maxTCPdataSize  //!< maximum size of a TCP datagram (400 Bytes seems a good size)
        );

    if (!r) {
        printf("setup finished successfully!\n");
        printf("===================================\n");
    } else {
        printf("setup error: %i \n", r);
        printf("===================================\n");
    }
    return r;
}

// -----------------------------------------
// test

enum eStates {
    eState_std = 0,
    eState_stressTest = 1,
    eState_multiTX = 2
};

int stateID = eState_std;
#define  dSTsize (1024 * 1024)
uint8_t STB[dSTsize];


int rxCB (uint8_t * pData, size_t amount) {
    size_t i;

    switch (stateID) {
        case eState_std:
            pData[amount] = 0;
            printf("rx: %s\n",pData);
            break;
        case eState_stressTest:
            for (i = 0; i < dSTsize; i++) {
                if (pData[i] != (uint8_t)((size_t)i & 0xFF)) {
                    fprintf(stderr, "stress test error at position %i\n",(int) i);
                    fflush(stdout);
                    return 0;
                }
            }
            printf("rx: stress test successful\n");
            break;
        case eState_multiTX:
            printf("rx %iBytes\n", (int)amount);
            break;
    }
    fflush(stdout);
    return 0;
}


int main(void) {
    const size_t dummyStrLen = 1024;
    char szDummy[dummyStrLen];
    size_t i;
    int r, am, j;

    // pre init for the stress test
    for (i = 0; i < dSTsize; i++) {
        STB[i] = (uint8_t)((size_t)i & 0xFF);
    }


    printf("TCP demo\n");

    if (TCPcontrolInitFromStdIn(rxCB, 4096, 500)) goto errorExit;


    printf("commands:\n s - send\n t - tx stress test\n a - activate/deactivate rx for stress test\n m - multi tx test\n h - help\n e - exit\n");
    for(;;) {
        printf("command: ");
        fgets(szDummy, dummyStrLen, stdin);
        switch(tolower(szDummy[0])) {
            case 's':
                stateID = eState_std;
                fgets(szDummy, dummyStrLen, stdin);
                szDummy[strcspn(szDummy, "\r\n")] = 0;
                r = TCPcontrolSend((uint8_t *)szDummy, strlen(szDummy)+1);
                if(r) {
                    fprintf(stderr,"sending data failed with code %i(%s)\n", r, strerror(errno));
                } else {
                    printf("succeeded\n");
                }
                break;
            case 't':
                printf("sending packets...\n");
                r = TCPcontrolSend(STB, dSTsize);

                if (r) {
                    fprintf(stderr,"stress test sending data failed with code %i\n", r);
                } else {
                    printf("succeeded\n");
                }
                break;
            case 'a':
                stateID = eState_stressTest;
                printf("stress test RX now active\n");
                break;
            case 'm':
                stateID = eState_multiTX;
                printf("amount of transmissions: ");
                fgets(szDummy, dummyStrLen, stdin);
                szDummy[strcspn(szDummy, "\r\n")] = 0;
                am = atoi(szDummy);
                for (j = 0; j < am; j++) {
                    printf("tm %i...", j);
                    sprintf(szDummy,"tm %i",j);
                    r = TCPcontrolSend((uint8_t *)szDummy, strlen(szDummy)+1);
                    if (!r) printf("successful\n");
                        else printf("failed\n");
                }
                break;
            case 'h':
                printf("commands:\n s - send\n t - tx stress test\n a - activate/deactivate rx for stress test\n m - multi tx test\n h - help\n e - exit\n");
                break;
            case 'e':
                goto stdExit;
        }
    }


stdExit:

    TCPcontrolClose ();
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;

errorExit:

    TCPcontrolClose ();
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```

a note to the stress test and the initial connection. Under weak WLAN connections it could took some time.

Answer (score 1):

If you need a UDP file transfer application, try [UFTP](http://uftp-multicast.sourceforge.net).

I wrote it primarily for multicast, but it works just as well with unicast.  Give it a try, and let me know how it goes.

Comment: I took a look. I think for my simple problem your solution is a little oversized. But anyway it's looking quite well developed. Thanks so far.
Now I am trying TCP sockets.